# equivalent to: my_obj.height += 10; in adobe animate HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, canvas, animate-cc

I have this in my old AS3 project:

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onReset);
function onReset(e:MouseEvent):void{
    my_obj.height += 10;
}
```

What's it's equivalent in adobe animate HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you will have to modify to get the equivalent functionality. First off, you will need to reference your objects properly on the Stage using the keyword 'this'. Additionally, you'll have to update the way you reference your event listener. You'll need to update the way you create your function (remove 'void' and ':event'). Finally, you will need to include the bounds of the MovieClip that you're referencing.

Here's an example on how you can rewrite your code:

```
//Create a reference to the object
var my_obj = this.my_obj;

//Add an event listener
this.button_1.addEventListener("click", onReset);

//On Reset function handler
function onReset(e){
    my_obj.getBounds().height += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no special difference, just port it to Javascript

1. `MouseEvent.CLICK` is not part of **JS** so could be changed
2. `variable:Type` is not supported in **JS**

try it

```
button_1.addEventListener("click", onReset);
function onReset(e) {
    my_obj.height += 10;
}
```

Comment: you realize that my problem is with the "my_obj.height += 10;" part right?
and you forgot a whole bunch of "this." in front of everything.